# grails 2.3: tests not recognized by test-app

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I am playing with the recently released grails 2.3.0. Unfortunately, test-app is not recognizing tests. Here is what I did to produce the problem.

First, make a new app and create a controller:

```
$ grails create-app firstApp
$ cd firstApp/
$ grails create-controller foo
```

I got the following files from creating the controller foo:

```
| Created file grails-app/controllers/firstapp/FooController.groovy
| Created file grails-app/views/foo
| Created file test/unit/firstapp/FooControllerSpec.groovy
```

Then, I edited the file `FooControllerSpec.groovy` by adding `assert 1 == 2` in the auto-generated method `void "test something"()`. Here is the full content of `FooControllerSpec.groovy` after my editing:

```
package firstapp

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(FooController)
class FooControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        assert 1 == 2
    }
}
```

Then I ran the following command:

```
$ grails test-app
```

However, no tests were run. Here is the output from that command:

```
| Completed 0 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in /Users/jianbao.tao/projects/grails/firstApp/target/test-reports
```

My platform is OS X 10.8.5 + grails 2.3.0 + Java 1.6.0_51 + groovy 2.1.6. Can anyone tell me what's going on here, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grails 2.3.0 ships with spock test framework by default. So, the test should look like:

```
void "test something"() {
    expect:
      1 == 2
}
```

For details on spockframework, visit [docs](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/).