# Grails basic unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails

Ok this should be really simple and basic, but I can't understand what's going on.

I created a Grails app with a few Domain classes. I see it created a test case class that looks like this:

```
package subasto6

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage       instructions
 */
@TestFor(Oferta)
class OfertaSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void testSomething() {
    assertEquals("foo", "bar")
    fail "gfsdger";
}

void testFoo() {
    fail "foo"
}
```

}

Now when I run this I get:

```
 | Loading Grails 2.3.0  
 | Configuring classpath. 
 |Environment set to test..... 
 | Running without daemon... 
 | Compiling 1 source files. 
 | Running 2 unit tests... 
 | Completed 0 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 1s
 | Tests PASSED - view reports in
 C:\Facultad\Seminario\workspaceSTS\Subasto6\target\test-reports
```

Why do they not fail? It says it runs the two tests, but then it says 0 completed and nothing fails, when it really should. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808228/2051952). These are spock specifications. [Additional reference](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/).

Comment: That hit the nail. Thank you very much!